# Is it possible to add a Bulletted list mode in TextArea JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

[image]

Just like in Word or WYSIWYG editor, I want the ability to make `TextArea` perform a simple bullet list.

Comment: No, `TextArea` does not support this. Consider using a [`HTMLEditor`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/HTMLEditor.html) instead.

Comment: I would but that adds a lot of html tags as the output. Since the bullet is an ascii character, and TextArea already supports ascii, new lines and tabs, I had a feeling there might have been a way...

Comment: You could possibly experiment with using a `TextFormatter`, replacing all `\n` in a change with `\n\t` plus a bullet character, or similar. But that wouldn't give you the same block indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using RichTextFX `StyleClassedTextArea` :

[image]

```
public static final String BULLET_CODE = "  \u2022\t";

        textArea.setOnKeyPressed(event ->
        {
            KeyCode code = event.getCode();
            if (KeyCode.ENTER.equals(code))
            {

                textArea.moveTo(textArea.getCaretPosition() - 1);
                textArea.selectParagraph();
                if (StringUtils.startsWith(textArea.getSelectedText(), BULLET_CODE))
                {
                    textArea.moveTo(textArea.getCaretPosition() + 1);

                    textArea.lineStart(NavigationActions.SelectionPolicy.CLEAR);
                    textArea.insertText(textArea.getCaretPosition(), BULLET_CODE);
                } else
                {
                    textArea.moveTo(textArea.getCaretPosition() + 1);

                }
                textArea.deselect();

            }
        });
```

And adding a button that inserts a bullet:

```
        addBullet.setOnAction((ActionEvent t) ->
        {
            textArea.selectLine();
            if (!StringUtils.startsWith(textArea.getSelectedText(), BULLET_CODE))
            {
                textArea.deselect();
                textArea.lineStart(NavigationActions.SelectionPolicy.CLEAR);
                textArea.insertText(spellCheckArea.getTextArea().getCaretPosition(), BULLET_CODE);
                textArea.lineEnd(NavigationActions.SelectionPolicy.CLEAR);
            }
            textArea.deselect();
            textArea.requestFocus();
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

Nevertheless you can insert [bullet point unicode character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm) in your TextArea
with the code "\u2022".

Comment: true, that would give you the char - but not formatting, or would it?

Comment: Sure, up to you to code the next step (for example listen to the typed characters like dot+space and insert a tab in front of the line).

Comment: actually .. not up to me - it's you who is answering and who should make your answer useful :)

Comment: I ended up creating the feature using a StyleClassedTextArea from the RichTextFX library.